# What is d:IsOptimized in Expressions Blend?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, syntax, expression-blend, blend

Just out of curiously, what is d:IsOptimized in Expressions Blend?

While I know that d: is a namespace for design-time attributes, does anyone know what d:IsOptimized actually does?  Is there anywhere that these Blend-specific attributes are documented?

It's not in the design-time attributes supported (and documented) by Visual Studio:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff602277(VS.95).aspx

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When Expression blend optimizes out certain animations (changing single key-frames to smaller From-To animation), that marker is left behind to give Blend clues. The optimization is converted back to a keyframe for editing purposes when Blend loads it.

Sorry, I don't know where these are documented.